# Matching color bar tape to replace dirty white tape?

Tags: road-bike, parts, handlebar-tape

My father has one a Trek 4.3 Domane from 2014 with white bicycle tape that is very dirty now and could use to be replaced(christmas gift for him). What color tape/product should I get that will still match the bike and not fade to as bad a color as the white does? I'm open to other colors, if they still match.[image]

Comment: huh? you came on here to ask us what colour we like? Go to your bike shop, and concentrate on getting a decent quality tape. Colour is irrelevant, although as you have already found, light colours will show dirt.

Comment: Indeed. Voting to close as opinion based. Whats more important is picking a tape which is comfortable. The default tapes Trek specs are typically good in this regard.

Comment: Bar tape color should match saddle color. Also that tape isn't even dirty. Unless he's complaining about it, I wouldn't buy him new tape.

Comment: Also voting to close. Try cleaning the tape.

Comment: I just go to a sporting goods place and buy hockey tape.  Comes in several colors.  Gets dirty fairly fast, but it's easy to apply -- just put it over the existing tape -- and when it gets dirty just add another layer.

Comment: (Note that replacing bar tape is not as easy as it looks.  The stuff is really poorly designed -- dunno why no one's ever improved on it -- and it's hard to apply such that it won't shift with use.)

Comment: Bar tapes are washable, by the way. Just avoid washing machines. Use washing solution for frame and stuff and wipe the tape aggressively until clean.

Comment: Even red a color prone to fade is not going fade noticeably before wears out.  Clean that tape before you give up on it.  Dirty tape still works.  I would get a light or something else before I replaced that tape.

Answer (score 2):

According to [rule 8](http://www.velominati.com/the-rules/#8), your choices are black, white, or try to match it to the blue frame color, which my be difficult.

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to make the best out of this question by giving what is hopefully a helpful answer to others. You would be really surprised just how clean you can get synthetic or cork bar tape, even if it's white, with a little bit of [orange degreaser](https://www.google.com/search?q=orange%20degreaser&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). Get a clean, preferably white rag, pour some on, and take one end of the towel in each hand and scrub the tape as if you were shining a shoe. Without much effort you can get it looking nearly brand new again.